# Why I can't close pull request by cherry-pick on github

Tags: git, github

I received a pull request (someone wanted to merge their commits they made in a forked repository) on one of my github repositories.

Because I didn't like something in their commits, I wanted to modify them by another commit before pushing this to master branch.

In order to do that, I cherry picked their commits into my master branch, then made another commit fixing the issues and then pushed it all on github.

However, this didn't close the pull request and because I already had their commits in my history I didn't want to click the "merge" button because I didn't want break my repository somehow. Why I can't close such a request by using cherry-pick? What's a difference between merging 2 repositories using the internal github's command and manual cherry pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refuse that pull request.

You can only merge it in the way it is. Or deny it entirely. You cannot pick some commits and make Git (and subsequently GitHub) recognize that this is your "merge" - it is not. It is your commits that may look like the other commits, but based on a different parent commit.

The other option would be to communicate with the pull requester to make them rearrange things the way you like it, and then merge. But because you already cherry-picked the commits you like, this is now obsolete.

Comment: Yes, I kind of understand this, but I cherry picked ALL of the commits that were in the pull request. If I picked only parts of the pull request, it would make sense that it's not possible to recognize this. So basically, if I did this the either way, my commit history (git log) would look identical in both cases. That's why I don't understand that github see a difference in this.

Comment: @Petr, this is because afaik GitHub doesn't treat pull requests as traditional merges, which means that your cherry picking isn't recognized as being part of the pull request initiated by the contributor.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GitHub, but with the was Git works: If you merge, you create a commit with two parents (the two last commits of each branch). When cherry-picking, your commits only have one parent, and the connection of where this pick came from is lost. Also, if you don't use the picks exactly as they are, you are changing the hash ids for each commit. And last but not least: If you cherry-pick and commit to a different parent id, the hash of this commit must also change, even if the code change was not altered. So if you want to merge: Merge. There is no alternative.